# async_connect successfull if server is not running

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to check whether `boost::asio::async_connect` was successfull, but I do not get an error, even if the server is not startet. How do I check for success correctly? Thank you!

`main.cpp`

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "tcp_client.h"
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp tcp;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char host[16] = "127.0.0.1";
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        TCP_Client client(host, io_service);
        io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

`tcp_client.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp tcp;

class TCP_Client
{
public:
    TCP_Client(std::string newHost, boost::asio::io_service& io_service);

private:
    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
};
```

`tcp_client.cpp`

```
#include "tcp_client.h"

TCP_Client::TCP_Client(std::string host, boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket(io_service), acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 12121))
{
    tcp::resolver resolver(socket.get_io_service());
    tcp::resolver::query query(host, "12121");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket, endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&TCP_Client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void TCP_Client::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error && socket.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error handle connect:" << error << std::endl;
    }
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: What does happen?

Comment: It just prints out "Connected".

Comment: Your code looks right. Are you 100% sure it isn't connected? What does `netstat` say?

Comment: You have a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` listening on the address/port you're connecting to -- right?

Comment: I create the acceptor in the initializer list of the constructor. Of course I also have an accepor in the server app. But in this case I want to test the client, if the server does not exists. If the server is running everything works fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz netstat says that the client is litening to my port. Does that mean my application is connecting to itself? How can I prevent this?

Comment: That's what I meant.  The `acceptor` ctor you're using automatically does `bind` and `listen`.  So I think you're creating a send-to-self loop.  Try changing the acceptor port to something else and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! Do I understand it correctly? In the client-app I assign the acceptor to the clientport, which should be different to the server port which I assign to the acceptor in the server-app and the service assigned to `tcp::resolver::query` should be the serverport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an acceptor bound to the port:

```
... acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 12121)) ...
```

So you're connecting to yourself. Your client does not need, and should not have, a TCP acceptor unless it's supposed to accept TCP connections.